# Regex for specific list

Tags: c#, regex

I need to extract from each line with comma separated numbers (C#)

```
test    35,1    35,2    35,3    35,4    35,5

test2   35,1    35,2    35,3    35,4    35,5

test3   35,1    35,2    35,3    35,4    35,5


test    35,1    35,2    35,3    35,4    35,5

test2   35,1    35,2    35,3    35,4    35,5

test3   35,1    35,2    35,3    35,4    35,5
```

I would like to have a group name test that would have two matches

```
test    35,1    35,2    35,3    35,4    35,5
test    35,1    35,2    35,3    35,4    35,5
```

What I've achieved so far

```
(?>test(?>(?<test>[\w\s,]+)\n))
```

but all the text is selected till the last line

Comment: Something like [this](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3etest%5cb(%3f%3e%5cs*(%3f%3ctest%3e%5cd%2b(%3f%3a%2c%5cd%2b)*))%2b)&i=test++++35%2c1++++35%2c2++++35%2c3++++35%2c4++++35%2c5%0d%0atest2+++35%2c1++++35%2c2++++35%2c3++++35%2c4++++35%2c5%0d%0atest3+++35%2c1++++35%2c2++++35%2c3++++35%2c4++++35%2c5%0d%0atest++++35%2c1++++35%2c2++++35%2c3++++35%2c4++++35%2c5%0d%0atest2+++35%2c1++++35%2c2++++35%2c3++++35%2c4++++35%2c5%0d%0atest3+++35%2c1++++35%2c2++++35%2c3++++35%2c4++++35%2c5)?

Comment: Life saver thank you could you please help me make the same regex with all the groups test test2 and test3 with the same format so that i can capture all matches

Comment: You can just add `\d*` after `test`: `(?>test\d*\b(?>\s*(?<test>\d+(?:,\d+)*))+)` - and the numbers will be all in Group 2 capture collection.

Comment: That works and if the name is different from those? sorry for all the questions but regex expressions are new to me

Comment: Sorry for another question but the regex you showed me only selects the last number 35,5. I need the complete line with all the numbers like this: test2   35,1    35,2    35,3    35,4    35,5. Can you help me please?

Comment: These values are inside the CaptureCollection of Group 1. Once I have a minute  I could post the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer in c# i cant get to these values could you please help me with a regex that returns the matches for: test    35,1    35,2    35,3    35,4    35,5 for example

Comment: Please check [this demo](http://ideone.com/3nuXKH) and let me know if it works the way you expect. `match.Groups["key"].Value` contains the `test`+number and `match.Groups["test"].Captures` holds all the float values.

Answer (score 2):

You can name your capture groups like this: `(?<name>expression)`. Writing the rest is fairly simple. Start with the literal string `test`, followed by any whitespace characeter, to ensure you don't capture `test2` or `test3`. Then capture all remaining characters to get the rest of your line.

```
(?<test>test\s.*)
```

You can then access your named groups like this:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"(?<test>test\s.*)");
foreach(Match match in matches)
{
    string result = match.Groups["test"].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the regex you can leverage:

```
(?<key>test\d*)\b(?>\s*(?<test>\d+(?:,\d+)*))+
```

See the [regex demo here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3Ckey%3Etest%5Cd*)%5Cb(%3F%3E%5Cs*(%3F%3Ctest%3E%5Cd%2B(%3F%3A%2C%5Cd%2B)*))%2B&i=test%20%20%20%2035%2C1%20%20%20%2035%2C2%20%20%20%2035%2C3%20%20%20%2035%2C4%20%20%20%2035%2C5%0D%0Atest2%20%20%2035%2C1%20%20%20%2035%2C2%20%20%20%2035%2C3%20%20%20%2035%2C4%20%20%20%2035%2C5%0D%0Atest3%20%20%2035%2C1%20%20%20%2035%2C2%20%20%20%2035%2C3%20%20%20%2035%2C4%20%20%20%2035%2C5%0D%0Atest%20%20%20%2035%2C1%20%20%20%2035%2C2%20%20%20%2035%2C3%20%20%20%2035%2C4%20%20%20%2035%2C5%0D%0Atest2%20%20%2035%2C1%20%20%20%2035%2C2%20%20%20%2035%2C3%20%20%20%2035%2C4%20%20%20%2035%2C5%0D%0Atest3%20%20%2035%2C1%20%20%20%2035%2C2%20%20%20%2035%2C3%20%20%20%2035%2C4%20%20%20%2035%2C5), the `key` named group will hold the `test`+digit(s) value and the `test` group will hold all the numbers after the key inside a `CaptureCollection` (`match.Groups["test"].Captures`):

[image]

Here is an IDEONE demo showing how you can retrieve these values in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var strs = new List<string> { "test    35,1    35,2    35,3    35,4    35,5",
        "test2   35,1    35,2    35,3    35,4    35,5",
        "test3   35,1    35,2    35,3    35,4    35,5",
        "test    35,1    35,2    35,3    35,4    35,5",
        "test2   35,1    35,2    35,3    35,4    35,5",
        "test3   35,1    35,2    35,3    35,4    35,5"};

        var pattern = @"(?<key>test\d*)\b(?>\s*(?<test>\d+(?:,\d+)*))+";
        foreach (var s in strs)
        {
            var match = Regex.Match(s, pattern, RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);  
            if (match.Success) 
            {                     // DEMO
                var key = match.Groups["key"].Value;
                var tests = match.Groups["test"].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(m => m.Value).ToList();
                Console.WriteLine(key);
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", and ", tests));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
test
35,1, and 35,2, and 35,3, and 35,4, and 35,5
test2
35,1, and 35,2, and 35,3, and 35,4, and 35,5
test3
35,1, and 35,2, and 35,3, and 35,4, and 35,5
test
35,1, and 35,2, and 35,3, and 35,4, and 35,5
test2
35,1, and 35,2, and 35,3, and 35,4, and 35,5
test3
35,1, and 35,2, and 35,3, and 35,4, and 35,5
```